# Using MapReduce API To Copy Files Inside HDFS With Gzip Compression

Tags: dictionary, copy, mapreduce, gzip, reduce

I'm writing an archiving program in Java.  The files that will be archived already reside in HDFS.  I need to be able to move the files from one location in HDFS to another location, with the final files being compressed with Gzip.  The files to be moved can be quite large, and thus using the HDFS API to move them and compress them can be quite inefficient.  So I was thinking that I could write a mapreduce job into my code to do that for me.

However, I have been unable to find any examples that show me how I could copy those files using the MapReduce API and have them output in gzip format.  In fact, I'm even struggling to find a programmatic example of how to copy files inside of HDFS through mapreduce at all.

Can anybody shed some light on how I can accomplish this with the MapReduce API?

Edit: Here's the job configuration code I have so far, which was adapted from the help that Amar has given me:

```
        conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", true); 
        conf.set("mapred.output.compression.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(LogArchiver.class);
        job.setJobName("ArchiveMover_"+dbname);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        //job.setMapperClass(IdentityMapper.class);
        //job.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(NonSplittableTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(archiveStaging+"/"+dbname+"/*/*"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(archiveRoot+"/"+dbname));
        job.submit();
```

Here is the class declaration for NonSplittableTextInputFormat which is inside of the LogArchiver class

```
public class NonSplittableTextInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
    public NonSplittableTextInputFormat () {
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this can help or not, but have you looked into Hadoop Streaming? http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming

Comment: It may very well be that I need to resort to that, but I would prefer a way to do it through the MapReduce API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write a [custom jar implementation](http://bigdataspeak.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/emr-streaming-job-using-java-code-for-mapper-and-reducer-creating-custom-jar/) with `IdentityMapper` and `IdentityReducer`.
Instead of plain text files, you can generate gzip files as your output. Set the following configurations in `run()` :

```
conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", true); 
conf.set("mapred.output.compression.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
```

In order to ensure that number of files in input and output are same, just that the output files must be gzipped, you have to do 2 things:

1. Implement a NonSplittableTextInputFormat
2. Set reduce tasks to zero.

In order to ensure that one file per mapper is read, you may extend the `TextInputFormat` as follows:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
public class NonSplittableTextInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path file) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use the above implementation as :

```
job.setInputFormatClass(NonSplittableTextInputFormat.class);
```

To set reduce tasks to zero, do the following:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

This would get the job done for you but for one last thing that file names won't be the same! But I am sure for this too there must be a work-around here.

Comment: You have certainly gotten me a long way towards my goal.  I just have two problems now.  1)  let's say I have a directory structure like so:
top_level/second_level/third_level/file, 
top_level/second_level/third_level2/file

How could I make it so the output matches the directory structure of the input?  Right now it just places all the output files in a single directory.

2)  There seems to be a number preceeding each line of the output files.  It increments with each line.  Almost looks like a character count.  How do I ensure that number doesn't get in the output?

Comment: Okay, so I was able to fix problem number two by implementing my own version of the TextOutputFormat class that excluded output of the key.  Still trying to figure out how to make the directory structures match up between input and output though.

Comment: I think you may solve this using the MultipleTextOutputFormat explained here: http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat

Comment: For this, you will need to first read the input file path using somehting like following in the `map()`: `((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName()`, and then use this to set the key of the output accordingly, and the complete payload as the value. Read above link first, then you might understand it better. Let's see if this helps.

Comment: Okay, so in order to use the fix you defined above, I had to update my code to use the new API version ("mapreduce" instead of "mapred").  It compiles fine now, but I get this error at runtime: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: LogArchiver$NonSplittableTextInputFormat.<init>()

NonSplittableTextInputFormat is inside the LogArchiver class and I have an empty constructor defined.  So I don't understand why it keeps throwing that exception.

I've included the NonSplittableTextInputFormat class declaration in my post above.

Comment: Fixed the NoSuchMethodException.  Had to move NonSplittableTextInputFormat to its own jar.  Now I'm off to try to implement the fix you outlined above.

Comment: you may use the old API itself for getting the filename. I guess it may be done using: `((FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName()`. I am not 100% sure about this, but it should be present.

Comment: Yeah figured that out a little while ago actually.  I've got it working (almost) like it should.  It does everything I want it to, but some jobs are failing with this exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): Lease mismatch on /archives/db/table/dt=2013-01-06/part-00000.gz owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1472673630_1 but is accessed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1612006201_1.  To me that error would seem to indicate that multiple mappers are trying to create the file at the same time.  Is that what you get out of it?

Comment: I can't seem to find much useful information on the web about that error.

Comment: yeah that is what I could also make of it. You could try one more thing, remove the constraint of reducer being zero, emit key to be the filepath from mapper and rest payload as the value. And if you are using the MultipleTextOutputFormat and IdentityReducer respectively for outputformat and reducer class, then you may get success.

Comment: This does it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianHelm: How did you solve problem 1, Directory structure. Output i get after MR is part-m-0000.gz . Is there anyway I can consolidate all the files and create one zip file.